# Does Ubuntu import the Universe repository from Debian?

Tags: repository, official-repositories

Does Ubuntu import the `Universe` repository from Debian?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mostly yes, from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/ForDebianDevelopers

> **Packages**
>
> Most source packages in all Ubuntu components (about 4 in 5 at the
>   time of this writing) are copied unmodified from Debian, but other
>   sources include apt-get.org, REVU, directly from organisations such as
>   Blackdown and WineHQ, software which has been packaged by Ubuntu
>   developers, and packages created specifically for Ubuntu.
>
> In some cases, the same upstream software is packaged separately in
>   Ubuntu and in Debian, though this is to be avoided unless there is a
>   justifiable reason to do so.
>
> Where packages in Debian and Ubuntu have a common heritage, the
>   packages use version numbers which reflect this.

This only refers to source packages - all binary packages are built on launchpad using the current toolchain in Ubuntu